# How to increment the value of a variable while writing to a txt file C #

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, txt

I have the following program:

Database (if you can call it that on text files)

When writing to a text file, I need to increase the record id by one

How can I not understand / find with the help of which method it is possible to implement a loop in which I will increase the id, can anyone tell me?

**I have a method by which I can format a text file from WPF text boxes**:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("D:\\123.txt", true))
{
    while (sr.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        id++;
        using (StreamWriter txt = new StreamWriter("D:\\123.txt", true))
        {
            txt.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}\n", id, TBName, TBLName, TBMName, TBInfo, TBMat, TBFiz));
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Данные успешно сохранены!");
    }
}
```

How can the id increase by 1 with each new entry in the text file?

The output of information to the datagrid was as follows:

```
    private void Work()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Student> list = new List<Student>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName, true))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var parsed = line.Split(' ');
                    list.Add(new Student
                        (
                           Convert.ToInt32(parsed[0]),
                           parsed[1],
                           parsed[2],
                           parsed[3],
                           Convert.ToInt32(parsed[4]),
                           Convert.ToInt32(parsed[5]),
                           Convert.ToInt32(parsed[6])
                        )); 
                }
            }
            DGridStudents.ItemsSource = list;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: To increase something you need to know its initial value and then add the increment to that value. So, or you read back all the lines in the file counting them (assuming no holes in the numbers already written) or you keep the last value written in some other related file. Of course this is something that you get gratis from a database system

Comment: The fact of the matter is that if I read and write in one method, I will have an exception of the type:(

The process cannot access the file "Path to file" because this file is in use by another process)

Comment: Of course, you have opened for reading then you cannot open again the same file for writing until you close it first

Comment: Use the `ReadLines` and `WriteAllLines` or `AppendAllLines` methods from the static `File` class. `ReadLines` allows you to iterate through the file with a simple `foreach` and automatically opens and closes the file. They are wrappers around `StreamReader` and `StreamWrite` and make your life easier. Also, write to a temp file first, then delete the old one (or rename it to *.bak) and finally rename the temp file to match the original file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown has some problems. First you cannot write in a file that you have opened for reading using the StreamReader/StreamWriter classes. But even if you can, look closely at how it works. First you open the file, then you start a loop reading a line, then writing a new line in the same file, then reading the next line (and that next line could be the same one you have just written).
In the better outcome your file will fill your disk.

To increment the value used as id in the last line you could approach with this

```
// First read the whole file and get the last line from it
int id = 0;
string lastLine = File.ReadLines("D:\\123.txt").LastOrDefault();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
{
    // Now split and convert the value of the first splitted part
    var parts = line.Split();
    if(parts.Length > 0)
    {
        Int32.TryParse(parts[0], out id);
    }
}
 
// You can now increment and write the new line
id++
using (StreamWriter txt = new StreamWriter("D:\\123.txt", true))
{
     txt.WriteLine($"{id} {TBName} {TBLName} {TBMName} {TBInfo} {TBMat} {TBFiz}");
}
```

This approach will force you to read the whole file to find the last line. However you could add a second file (and index file) to your txt with the same name but with the *idx* extension. This file will contain only the last number written

```
int id = 0;
string firstLine = File.ReadLines("D:\\123.idx").FirstOrDefault();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
{
    // Now split and convert the value of the first splitted part
    var parts = line.Split();
    if(parts.Length > 0)
    {
        Int32.TryParse(parts[0], out id);
    }
}
id++
using (StreamWriter txt = new StreamWriter("D:\\123.txt", true))
{
     txt.WriteLine($"{id} {TBName} {TBLName} {TBMName} {TBInfo} {TBMat} {TBFiz}");
}
File.WriteAllText("D:\\123.idx", id.ToString());
```

This second approach is probably better if the txt file is big because it doesn't require to read the whole txt file but there are more points of possible failure. You have two files to handle and this double the chances of IO errors and of course we are not even considering the multiuser scenario.
A database, even one based of a file like SQLite or Access are better suited for these tasks.

Comment: The second option seems to me better, thanks!

Comment: And you can also tell me what needs to be corrected now when outputting information to the date grid from txt, the fact is that now I get an error (exception) that the line was not in the correct format, as I understand it because of \ n Completed in the question, how I output to datagrid

Comment: Please post a new question with the details of the code working on the datagrid.